# Wordpress: Override php file in plugins include folder

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to override the php file under `wp-content/plugins/salient-core/includes/nectar_maps/nectar_cta.php` because I need to customize some options in the returning array.

Therefore I tried to place a php file in my child theme under `wp-content/themes/salient-child/salient-core/includes/nectar_maps/nectar_cta.php` which doesn't work.

Also I figured out that the file is used in `wp-content/plugins/salient-core/includes/nectar-addons.php` as follows:

```
class WPBakeryShortCode_Nectar_Cta extends WPBakeryShortCode {}
vc_lean_map('nectar_cta', null, SALIENT_CORE_ROOT_DIR_PATH . 'includes/nectar_maps/nectar_cta.php');
```

Then I tried to use vc_lean_map with my path in functions.php:

```
vc_lean_map('nectar_cta', null, 'mypath');
```

Which also failed.

Is there any way to override this file in my child theme?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortuntately, filepath overriding in the manner you're desicribing works great for child-theming, but there is no analogue for plugins.

However - you're barking up the right tree!

From the [`vc_lean_map()`](https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/inner-api/vc_lean_map/) page in WPBakery<sup>1</sup> docs:

> ## `vc_lean_map()`
>
> Map new shortcodes to WPBakery Page Builder with “lazy” method. It means that attributes for shortcode will be built only when a system uses any data from mapped shortcode or shortcode is rendered in a content of the page(do_shortcode called).

This tells me that you're able to specify a new file to override the plugin file with, and that you're likely just calling it too early in your `functions.php` file.

Try something like this, to be sure that you're overriding after the visual composer plugin's done loading, so it doesn't overwrite your work. (A lower priority of `100` in the example, to be explicit about the intentions.)

```
<?php
// funcitons.php
add_action('plugins_loaded', function() {
  vc_lean_map('nectar_cta', null, 'yourpath');
}, 100);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>  WPBakery are the folks behind Visual Composer, which somehow ties into this salient theme you're using.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I just tried it and unfortunately it doesnt work.

Comment: It seems like the plugins_loaded event is not fired.. i tried to put a die into the function and it doesnt affect the page. I figured out that its fired even before the theme is loaded https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112593/why-is-plugins-loaded-not-called-fired. So i went with 'after_setup_theme ' which also doesnt work.